# ls -l but not ls --color=never slow on nfs-mounted directory, if simulatenously writing to that directory

Tags: linux, performance, nfs, ls, io

when I dump data into an NFS-mounted directory, reading files modes (e.g. `ls -l`) is several orders of magnitude slower than a plain file listing (e.g. `ls --color=never`). I would like to understand why.

If nothing's being written to that directory `ls -l` will return almost immediately. However, if I then create some IO with e.g. `dd if=/dev/zero of=dd.img count=100M && rm dd.img`, `ls -l` will hang for up to half a minute, but `ls --color=never` or `getdents` return almost immediately. In other words, as soon as file modes are read, `ls` stalls, but only if I write to the same directory at the same time. I see this behaviour in several directories mounted with different NFS options.

The client is running CentOS 6.1 client (Kernel version 2.6.32-358.2.1.el6.x86_64). I don't know what the server is running (some proprietary high-performance system) and I don't have admin rights. My question is simply whether this sort of behaviour is expected in certain scenarios and if so, which?

Many thanks,

Andreas

Comment: Are you comparing `ls -l` to `ls --color=never` or to `ls -l --color=never`?

Comment: The former. In other words `ls -l` and `ls --color=auto` are much slower (during IO) than `getdents` or `ls --color=never`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getdents` and `ls --color=never` require only reading the directory. 
`ls -l` and `ls --color=auto` require reading the directory
*and the inodes corresponding to all the directory entries*. 
(`ls -l`, because it needs to get the mode, link count, owner, size, and modification date,
because it displays those fields, and `ls --color=auto`, because it needs to get the mode
(and maybe link count and size),
because it determines color partly from file type (plain file, directory, fifo, symlink, etc.),
writeability, executability, setuid, setgid, and the sticky bit (and maybe link count and size).)

Getting a lot of information from a remote server can take a lot of time,
especially if it is distant or intrinsically slow (to include being heavily loaded). 
It is common for clients to cache results,
so, when the user asks for information that has already been retrieved,
the client can display the cached (saved) results rather than fetch them again.

> If nothing’s being written to the directory, `ls -l` will return almost immediately.

I suspect that the NFS client (part of your CentOS system) asks the NFS server, “What’s up?”,
and the server replies, “I’m bored.  Nothing’s happened here for a while.” 
So the client knows that it’s safe to show you the cached information.

> However, if I then create (… a file …), `ls -l` will hang for up to half a minute, …

The client asks, “What’s up?”, and the server replies, “Things have changed over here.” 
So the client knows that its cache is invalid,
and so it needs to re-read the directory and all the inodes (through the server). 
This would also be true for `ls --color=auto`.

> … but `ls --color=never` or `getdents` return almost immediately.

Since these commands don’t require the inode information,
the only thing that needs to be re-read is the directory itself, which takes much less time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, which makes intuitively sense. I'd upvote your answer if only I had 15 points reputation :) One question though: is the observed behaviour something you'd expect to see often or only under unusual server load? I see it every day in a supposedly high-performance setting, which is really annoying (tab-completion hangs as well).

Comment: Tab completion will look at more than the current directory depending on where on the line you are pressing tab. It also searches the execution path if it is on the first argument. You can speed that up by adding `updatedb` to one of the maintenance crontabs on a a system that has often changes.